# Why would Zhora be in Rachael's childhood photos?

Tags: blade-runner, blade-runner-series

The Tyrell Corporation has gone through a lot of trouble to construct Rachael's background, going so far as to implant real memories from Tyrell's niece. Part of this background are photos from her "childhood", which Rachael throws away in Deckard's apartment after learning about her real origin.

**Why would one of these photos contain (even if well hidden) Zhora, for Decker to discover using the ESPER machine?**

Is the photo from Tyrell's niece, with the implication that Zhora is a replicant of another family member of Tyrell's?

Comment: I thought Deckard was looking at Leon's pictures.

Comment: @TGnat you're right - Deckard went from the picture(s) of Rachael's childhood to the photos he found at Leon's  apartment/hotel room.

Comment: Ah, I missed that! You could post that as an answer @TGnat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Zhora was actually in Leon's photos, not Rachael's

[As mentioned in the comments by TGnat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157794/why-would-zhora-be-in-rachaels-childhood-photos/171116#comment413877_157794), the stack of photos that Deckard found in Leon's apartment actually belonged to Leon:

[image]
<sup>[img src](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1385/21267)</sup>

In one of the scenes following Deckard's discovery, Roy asks Leon:

> Did you retrieve your precious photos?

Additionally, it was not a childhood photo, rather a recent one.